# Burning iso images with wodim loses 2048 bytes at the end

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, disk-image, verification

If I burn an iso image with:

```
wodim -data  dev=/dev/scd0 in.iso
```

and then read it back out with:

```
dd if=/dev/scd0 of=out.iso
```

The resulting files are not identical, `out.iso` is 2048 bytes shorter then `in.iso`. What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Using Ubuntu 10.04 and Wodim 1.1.10

PS: dd always ends with an `Input/output error`, not just with this CD, but with all of them. I think its just a limitation of dd, but an explanation why it happens and how to avoid it would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems when burning my CDs with

```
cdrecord -v -eject dev=/dev/sr0 foo.iso
```

but it seems it's enough to change the burning mode from the default TAO (track at once) to DAO (disk at once):

```
cdrecord -v -eject -dao dev=/dev/sr0 foo.iso
```

To check if the burned CD is identical you can run md5sum:

```
md5sum /dev/sr0
```

'-dao' also takes care of the I/O error.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following with Ubuntu 10.4 to read in a CD that I want to copy or mount virtually:

dd if=/dev/sr0 of=mydisc.iso  bs=2048 conv=sync,notrunc

The sync and notrunc make sure that the last few bytes get written.  see "man dd" for details

Hotei